# Нормализация данных через полнотекстовый поиск postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql9.6

Имеется денормализированная выгрузка данных. В разных строках этой выгрузки содержатся данные по типу:

- "Карл-Вери-Штр. 34, 81739 Мюнхен, Германия"
- "Карл-Вери-Штрассе 34, 81739 Мюнхен, Германия"

И из-за того, что они минимально отличаются -
`to_tsvector(address) @@ plainto_tsquery(address2)` не может понять, что это один и тот же адрес.

Как сделать чтобы алгоритм понимал, что это одно и тоже?

Comment: для начала удостовериться, что это действительно ваша проблема. То есть именно ваша компания занимается логистикой или чем-то вроде того, из-за чего готовы тратить года, разбирая разные аномалии картографии в разной степени тщетности попыток наводить единообразие. То что два адреса выглядят похожими, IRL совсем не значит, что это не разные адреса. Например, садоводство "Дружный 1" и "Дружное 1" - это разные места, но дефолтные словари tsvector их приведут к одному виду, что будет грубая ошибка логистики.

Comment: К сожалению, это стало нашей проблемой. Но к счастью это не логистика, так что серьезных проблем быть не должно. Наткнулся на модуль pg_trgm и он похоже должен решить мою проблему.